# Why do apt-get and wget fail on my server when ping is working?

Tags: server, apt, updates

Yesterday my server still OK, but today after try to `sudo apt-get update` i got this error: [update process](http://pastebin.com/dLSqwZUq).

I try: 
`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`
And got [This](http://pastebin.com/HHndmp4V).Then try `update` again, but it's not solving my problem then show [May be still same error](http://pastebin.com/vC98WuBr).

---

I checked my internet connection try `ping google.com`, get result :

```
PING google.com (74.125.235.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 136.198.117.254: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Network(New nexthop: fw1.jvc-jein.co.id (136.198.117.6))
64 bytes from sin01s05-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.235.40): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=20.6 ms
64 bytes from sin01s05-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.235.40): icmp_req=2 ttl=53 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from sin01s05-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.235.40): icmp_req=3 ttl=53 time=33.0 ms
64 bytes from sin01s05-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.235.40): icmp_req=4 ttl=53 time=30.0 ms
64 bytes from sin01s05-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.235.40): icmp_req=5 ttl=53 time=28.1 ms
```

In some sites said that may be it caused by `getdeb server is down`.

---

try to install:

```
jeinqa@SVRQAR:~$ sudo apt-get install pastebinit
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

---

try :

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

result :

```
Status: inactive
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your test of simply attempting to fetch the google homepage, via `wget -q -O- http://www.google.com`, **there is a firewall *FW-1* on the machine/domain *jeinfw*** which seems to be blocking most, if not all outbound http access. (Ping/ICMP is *not* the same as http, so just because ping works doesn't mean http also does).

That's why `apt-get` is failing -- instead of the content it expects, whether text, bzip2, gzip or xz, it **always gets this HTML response from the firewall** when it requests any file:

```
<TITLE>Error</TITLE>
<BODY>
<H1>Error</H1>
FW-1 at jeinfw: Access denied.
</BODY>
```

### To resolve this:

You need to set up the HTTP proxy servers you were given! (I was told via chat!)

Assuming the server is http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080,

- Open the `/etc/profile` file with `sudo nano` (or your favorite editor). This file stores the system-wide variables initialized upon boot into the console.
- Add the following lines, modifying appropriately. You must duplicate in both upper-case and lower-case because (unfortunately) some programs only look for one or the other:

  ```
  http_proxy=http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
  https_proxy=http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
  ftp_proxy=http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
  no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
  HTTP_PROXY=http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
  HTTPS_PROXY=http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
  FTP_PROXY=http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
  NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
  ```

#### Then, set up the proxies for `apt-get` and Update Manager

- These programs will not obey the environment variables. Create a file called `95proxies` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, and include the following:

  ```
  Acquire::http::proxy "http://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/";
  Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/";
  Acquire::https::proxy "https://139.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/";
  ```

Finally, reboot the server to apply the changes.

Comment: it doesn't work. This is the apt-config dump output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1053970/

Comment: There's something between apt-get and the internet - notice the 0B(yte) downloads and the failure to even get the package list in the error logs.

Comment: Please pastebin your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and also `wget -O- http://www.google.com | pastebinit`

Comment: source.list :http://pastebin.com/rvWJWJU4 and http://pastebin.com/fxADy6Rr

Comment: OK, there is a proxy server or something in your internet which is blocking HTTP accesses. When you wget the google homepage, the length should be `Length: unspecified [text/html]`, NOT 82 which you get and the output should be http://paste.ubuntu.com/1058592/ .

Comment: But it mention `The program 'pastebinit' is currently not installed`. then try to install it i got error.

Comment: Well, that's because of the core problem we are trying to solve here. What does `wget -q -O- http://www.google.com/` display? Can you copy and paste that?

Comment: this the result : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1058606/

Comment: See edited answer - you need to have that firewall disabled.